# Unique set of chars in array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a small game where the user must select 1 of 5 characters (S, M, A, R or T) and insert it into a 5x5 2d-array. If the user inputs an invalid number or character, the program says it's an invalid character and does not insert it. This has worked with all except the characters where if you enter a correct character, it still displays as an invalid character.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class program{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    char[][] table = new char[5][5];
    table[0][0] = 'S';
    table[0][1] = 'M';
    table[0][2] = 'A';
    table[0][3] = 'R';
    table[0][4] = 'T';
    table[1][1] = 'T';
    table[1][2] = 'S';
    table[1][3] = 'M';
    table[2][2] = 'R';
    table[2][4] = 'S';
    table[3][1] = 'S';
    table[3][2] = 'M';
    table[4][2] = 'T';
    table[4][3] = 'S';

    int rows = 5;
    int columns = 5;


    for(int k = 0; k>=0; k++){
      for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
          System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }

      System.out.println("Enter a row (1-5): ");
      Scanner scRow = new Scanner(System.in);
      int m = scRow.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter a column (1-5): ");
      Scanner scCol = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n = scCol.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter a letter (S, M, A, R or T): ");
      Scanner scChar = new Scanner(System.in);
      char c = scChar.next().charAt(0);

      if (m < 1 || m > 5){
        System.out.println("Invalid: Enter a valid row. ");
      }
      if (n < 1 || n > 5){
        System.out.println("Invalid: Enter a valid column. ");
      }
      if (c != 'S' || c != 'M' || c != 'A' || c != 'R' || c != 'T'){
        System.out.println("Invalid: Enter a valid character. ");
      }

      table[(m-1)][(n-1)] = c;
    }
  }
}
```

I realize it has something to do with my if statement, but I am unsure of what to change the if statement to in order to get the intended results.

```
Example output:

S M A R T
  T S M
    R   S
  S M
    T S

Enter a row (1-5): **3**
Enter a column (1-5): **2**
Enter a letter (S, M, A, R or T): **A**

Invalid: Enter a valid character.
```

Another issue if anyone can help me is creating an end statement where the user gets the 2d-array completed and it says congrats, you got it. In order to do this, the user must have S M A R and T aligned in a 5-character line in any direction.

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: `Creating an end statement where the user gets the 2d-array completed and it says congrats, you got it.` can't you just count the number of times the user enters a valid character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `||` in your if statement to `&&`. Or, you could change your `!=` to `==`.

Right now, say if you enter an `S`, the first check passes, as the character is equal to `S`, but all the subsequent checks fail.

You can check that the character is **not in** your valid character set (by using `&&`).

```
if(c!='S' && c!='M' && c!='A' && c!='R' && c!='T')
```

Or, you can check that the entered character was **in** your valid character set using `==` and `||`.

```
if(c=='S' || c=='M' || c=='A' || c=='R' || c=='T')
```

Edit:

To check the end condition, you'll need to iterate over every column and every row to see if there are any repeating characters.  I'll assume you don't need to check diagonals.

```
static boolean checkEndCondition(char[][] table){
    return checkRows(table) && checkColumns(table);
}

static boolean isValidCharacter(char c){
    return c=='S' || c=='M' || c=='A' || c=='R' || c=='T';
}

static boolean checkRows(char[][] table){
    HashSet<Character> hashset = new HashSet<Character>();
    for(int y=0;y<table.length;y++){
        for(int x=0;x<table[0].length;x++){
            if(isValidCharacter(table[y][x]))
                hashset.add(table[y][x]);
            else
                return false;
        }
        if(hashset.size()!=5)
            return false;
        hashset.clear();
    }
    return true;
}
```

I use a hashset here.  There are other solutions, you just need some way of checking that no characters repeat.  I leave it to you to implement `checkColumns`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something. Do you have any suggestions for how to calculate an end statement to the game?

Comment: Sure, does the user just need to fill the 2D array with valid characters, or is that some extra condition that needs to be met?

Comment: Essentially, the user must solve the puzzle in a way that S M A R and T can be found in any given 5-char line but does not have to be in a particular order. If I recall, I believe I have to convert each 5-char line into an int to get its ASCII value and then use an if statement. But I am unsure of how to do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the accept!  I've given some code to check for the end state.